# Formatting btrfs for robust metadata

Tags: filesystems, backup, btrfs

If I make three partitions on a HDD, it appears that the default (which is `-m raid1`) will only store two copies of each metadata block.  Is there a way to store multiple copies, e.g. one on each partition where I made as many partitions as I wanted for the purpose?

I'm thinking of using this for off-line drives used to hold backups.